# Java hide null values retrieved from a database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, null

I use the code below to get all results from the database.

```
while(rs1.next()) {
    for(int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++)
        System.out.printf(rs1.getString(i)+"    ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

They come in form of:

```
1       google      com     null        
2       facebook    com     null        
3       youtube     com     null
4       bbc         com     uk
```

I want to not display the null value. Although still display rest of the record. 
Thank you!

Comment: Don't print in the case: `if(rs1 == null)`, or add `if(rs1 != null) System.out.printf(rs1.getString(i)+"    ");`. You may want to factor out the spaces in that case though.

Comment: You can replace null with empty string. `String cell = Optional.ofNullable(rs1.getString(i)).orElse(""); System.out.printf(cell +"    ");`

Comment: If you don't want to print the `NULL`, what do you want to print instead???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for nulls with a ternary...

```
for(int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++) {
    String printMe = rs1.getString(i)
    System.out.printf(printMe == null ? "" : printMe + "\t"); 
}
```

In this case, if `printMe` (your column value) is null, it just prints an empty string. I've substituted spaces for a tab, but you can print however you like.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check prior to the print:

```
for(int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++) {
    String s = rs1.getString(i)
    if (s != null) { 
       System.out.printf(s + "    "); 
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple null check before printing the column cell element.

```
while(rs1.next()) {
    for(int i = 1; i < columnsNumber; i++)
        System.out.printf(rs1.getString(i) == null ? "" : rs1.getString(i) + "\t");
    System.out.println();
}
```